# scrolling a background image and floating buttons

Tags: android

I need a screen that is filled with an image as background and three buttons floating over the image.   I created this fine in xml and in vertical orientation it does what I want.  However in landscape it doesnt so I have tried to add a scrollview and am getting very confused as to how to combine these elements correctly.   After various tries I reached the stage shown below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/home_container"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/alert"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" android:clickable="true"
    android:enabled="true" />
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="25px" android:paddingLeft="25px"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:paddingTop="90px"       android:id="@+id/toplinear"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:paddingRight="25px"
    android:gravity="top">
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/startprogrambutton" android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:text="@string/text1" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/button1" android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:background="@drawable/webview_buttons"
        android:text="@string/text2" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/button2" android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:background="@drawable/webview_buttons"
        android:text="@string/text3" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"></Button>
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:textSize="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/button3" android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" android:background="@drawable/webview_buttons"
        android:text="@string/text4" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"></Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now it errors with scrollview can only contain one child.   Is there some way to rearrange so that I can have my image and the floating buttons all scroll together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put both `ImageView` and `LinearLayout` in another Vertical `LinearLayout`. This solves your scrollView child problem.

```
<ScrollView>
<LinearLayout>
<Imageview />
<LinearLayout />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Why don't you give image as background for linearLayout with buttons, it will serve your purpose.

Comment: That stops it errorring but now the image is not a background but a seperate element above the buttons.  I forgot to mention that when it worked ok as non scrolling I had everything in a frame layout.  As I understand a scrollview is a frame layout I thought it would just replace it.

Comment: use the android:background="@drawable/alert" attribute for linear layout with buttons. remove the imageView. , yes you can replace it with frameLayout too. put that frameLayout inside the scrollview.

Comment: Thanks Yashwanth - the background attr didi it.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to scroll only your buttons and not the ImageView you can try this:

```
<LinearLayout>
    <Imageview />
    <ScrollView>
        <LinearLayout>
            <Button />
            <Button />
            <Button />
            <Button />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Just so you know, you're not limited to trying to find a single solution for both orientations.  You can have 2 separate layouts for both orientations by specifying separate layout xml files in a land & port directory.   See the official documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks for this helpful reference